# Screen goes black only when clicking system settings. Comes back on after 10 to 60 seconds

Tags: drivers, display, screen, system-settings, flicker

I am new to Ubuntu.  I just installed a fresh copy of 16.04 LTS on a Lenovo M8 3306 ThinkCentre desktop.

It is running great so far other than one weird problem in which I cannot find anyone else on google as having...

**Whenever I click on anything to do with system settings, the screen goes black for ~10-60 seconds.**  Clicking the following things causes this weird problem:

- "System Settings" icon in the menu bar
- "System Settings" menu item in the top right power dropdown
- "About This Computer" menu item in the top right power dropdown
- "Change Desktop background" in the right-click on desktop dropdown

When the screen comes back on, the thing that I clicked will be open.

I have tried opening and closing various other programs and folders, but nothing else causes the screen to go black.  It seems just anything that is somehow tied to system settings...

One more note:  When I first turn on the machine and log in, when it gets to the desktop, it flickers, showing the desktop being a really small square and being the normal size, very rapidly.  This stops after a few seconds.

Thanks for your help.

Here is some info:

```
Computer
Processor   4x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz
Memory  12106MB (1564MB used)
Operating System    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Display
Resolution  1920x1080 pixels
OpenGL Renderer Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop
X11 Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
(Using VGA)

Version
Kernel  Linux 4.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Compiled    #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:57 UTC 2017
C Library   Unknown
Default C Compiler  GNU C Compiler version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)
Distribution    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Loaded Modules
intel_rapl  Driver for Intel RAPL (Running Average Power Limit)
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    X86 PKG TEMP Thermal Driver
coretemp    Intel Core temperature monitor
kvm 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi  HDMI HD-audio codec
irqbypass   IRQ bypass manager utility module
snd_hda_codec_realtek   Realtek HD-audio codec
snd_hda_codec_generic   Generic HD-audio codec parser
snd_hda_intel   Intel HDA driver
snd_hda_codec   HDA codec core
crct10dif_pclmul    T10 DIF CRC calculation accelerated with PCLMULQDQ.
crc32_pclmul    
ghash_clmulni_intel GHASH Message Digest Algorithm, acclerated by PCLMULQDQ-NI
snd_hda_core    HD-audio bus
snd_hwdep   Hardware dependent layer
aesni_intel Rijndael (AES) Cipher Algorithm, Intel AES-NI instructions optimized
snd_pcm Midlevel PCM code for ALSA.
snd_seq_midi    Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer MIDI synth.
snd_seq_midi_event  MIDI byte  sequencer event coder
snd_rawmidi Midlevel RawMidi code for ALSA.
input_leds  Input -> LEDs Bridge
aes_x86_64  Rijndael (AES) Cipher Algorithm, asm optimized
snd_seq Advanced Linux Sound Architecture sequencer.
snd_seq_device  ALSA sequencer device management
snd_timer   ALSA timer interface
lrw LRW block cipher mode
glue_helper 
ablk_helper 
snd Advanced Linux Sound Architecture driver for soundcards.
soundcore   Core sound module
cryptd  Software async crypto daemon
intel_cstate    
intel_rapl_perf 
serio_raw   Raw serio driver
ie31200_edac    MC support for Intel Processor E31200 memory hub controllers
lpc_ich LPC interface for Intel ICH
mei_me  Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
mei Intel(R) Management Engine Interface
edac_core   Core library routines for EDAC reporting
mac_hid 
parport_pc  PC-style parallel port driver
ppdev   
lp  
parport 
autofs4 
hid_generic HID generic driver
usbhid  USB HID core driver
hid 
i915    Intel Graphics
i2c_algo_bit    I2C-Bus bit-banging algorithm
drm_kms_helper  DRM KMS helper
syscopyarea Generic copyarea (sys-to-sys)
sysfillrect Generic fill rectangle (sys-to-sys)
psmouse PS/2 mouse driver
sysimgblt   1-bit/8-bit to 1-32 bit color expansion (sys-to-sys)
e1000e  Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
fb_sys_fops Generic file read (fb in system RAM)
ahci    AHCI SATA low-level driver
drm DRM shared core routines
libahci Common AHCI SATA low-level routines
ptp PTP clocks support
pps_core    LinuxPPS support (RFC 2783) - ver. 5.3.6
wmi ACPI-WMI Mapping Driver
fjes    FUJITSU Extended Socket Network Device Driver
video   ACPI Video Driver

OpenGL
Vendor  Intel Open Source Technology Center
Renderer    Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Desktop
Version 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
Direct Rendering    Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue. Issue is over when switching to wayland. Don't know what caused it yet, but it's a workaround.